# what is the use of -1 command in a function in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have come across below function which uses -1 command

```
q)whereami:{-1 "cd ~ ",system "cd";} / defining the function
q)whereami[] / executing the function
cd ~ /Users/utsav/kdbScripts/db
```

**Could you please explain what is the use of -1 command in this function?**

Seems like it is used to provide the output in console in non string format, however not sure if that is the case.

If I try the function without -1 and semi-colon, and then display the output in console, it displays the output in string format.

```
whereami:{"cd ~ ",system "cd"}
whereami[]
"cd ~ /Users/utsav/kdbScripts/db"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `-1` is printing to standard out

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/handles/

A string displays embedded special characters:

```
q)"String with some\n\t special characters"
"String with some\n\t special characters"
```

If we want `\n` displayed as newline and `\t` as tab we can print to standard out with `-1` (or `1` - the difference being `-1` will auto print a newline at the end of your output)

```
q)-1 "String with some\n\t special characters"
String with some
         special characters
-1
```

`-1` returns `-1` after it prints the text so it is common to use `;` to suppress that return as it is not that useful is almost all cases.

```
q)-1 "String with some\n\t special characters";
String with some
         special characters
q)
```

Answer (score 2):

-1 is used to print the string (array) result to the console. The return value would be the connection handle and not the string. In the case without -1, it returns the string result as it is.
-1 is useful when you need to log info to the console of the running Q process.

There is more information here on the different permanent system handles: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/handles/#file-stdout-stderr

It is also good to note that neg handle adds a “\n” newline when printing. If you want to print/log in a single line you can use 1.